# azure devops , Invoke-Command to server with variables from variable group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have variable in variable group and I try to use them in `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock`.

And is not found the variable, not success to reach to variables in variable group.

The script run in PowerShell, in release:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName X -ScriptBlock {
Write-Host $env:Mypod
}
```

I read about argument list, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: not work , in the computer we login to hem to do the script is not recognize the variables from variable group

Comment: This is the usual way of passing an argument to Invoke-Command. ```$var1 = $env:Mypod

Invoke-Command -ComputerName X -ScriptBlock {
Write-Host $args[0]
} -ArgumentList $var1 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Dilly B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670623/dilly-b):

You can pass the argument to `Invoke-Command` to reach to variables in variable group:

```
$var1 = $env:Mypod  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName X -ScriptBlock { Write-Host $args[0] } -ArgumentList $var1
```

You can refer to [Use a variable group's secret and nonsecret variables in an Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cli/pipeline-variable-group-secret-nonsecret-variables?view=azure-devops) and [Azure DevOps: how to manage CI/CD variable groups using PowerShell](https://ranari.com/2020/03/26/devops-manage-variable-groups-powershell/)

Comment: and if I have 2 arguments , how can I set them in the list of argument list ? like that : -ArgumentList $var1, $var2? and use arg[0] \ arg[1]?